# Is there a way to require constructors that take particular arguments?

Tags: scala

I think what I'm trying to do is easy, but I'm not getting the right collection of search terms.  What I want is a trait that guarantees that all implementing classes have a constructor that can be invoked with an object of a known type.  The syntax ought to be:

```
trait Message {
  def this(rdr: msgpack.MsgReader): Message
}
```

but the compiler tells me it expects an equals sign.  Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Constructors cannot be part of an interface.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  Is there a way to mandate that implementations have a companion object that has a method of some signature?

Comment: You can take a hint from the collection hierarchy and force everything to have a 'companion: Factory' method, but that requires you have an instance before you can make more. You can also use typeclasses, which lifts that restriction, However, in general, Scala's type system doesn't allow you to move between companion types (and for good reason, as IMO they aren't really related).

Comment: The reason this isn't allowed is very simple: constructors aren't inherited. Imagine you have `trait Message { def this(i: Int) }`, `class MessageImpl(i: Int) extends Message` and `class Subclass extends MessageImpl(0)`. Now, is `Subclass` a `Message`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the typeclass pattern instead:

```
trait Message[T] {
  def read(reader: msgpack.MsgReader): T
  // Example of what would be a normal instance method.
  // thiz is similar to this, except because we're in another object it must be explicitly taken as parameter.
  // It's in a separate param list for convention and ease of currying
  def foo(thiz: T)(param1: Int): Boolean
}

// "Implementors" don't actually implement it, the behavior exists as its own singleton
class Foo { ... }

implicit object FooMessage extends Message[Foo] {
  // Note that this is not restricted to just constructors. If you want that then you are really out of luck. (And probably doing it wrong.)
  override def read(reader: msgpack.MsgReader) = ???
  override def foo(thiz: Foo)(param1: Int) = thiz.foo(param1)
}

// Usage
// Use an explicit, named implicit param to avoid implicitly
def readMsg[T: Message](reader: msgpack.MsgReader) = implicitly[Message[T]].read(reader)

val foo = readMsg[Foo](???)
```

Comment: This is neat, but for my application I liked your other suggestion better (forcing messages to be able to come up with a factory).  These are received messages, which means that on the sending end there is an instance to work with, so the sender can ask the message for the name of the factory and send that first, then the receiver can use the name to reflect and build a factory and use that to parse the received bytes.  I like it, thanks!